# Using a proxy with Vagrant & Puppet

Tags: debian, puppet, debian-squeeze, vagrant

I'm trying to run a puppet manifest which depends on the target machine having proxy settings to access the Internet.

I haven't been able to pass http_proxy_host as Puppet suggests (I believe its a bug?).

I've tried to update .bashrc on my Debian box (through the puppet manifest) though I'm not sure how to get the settings to take the first time round.

Instead I believe a solution would be to set/pass the env var http_proxy however I'm not sure how/where to do this with Vagrant.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/puppet-users/2aivOoYHwZ0/rjRkJx1zdjQJ suggests using a wrapper like so...

```
#!/bin/bash
export http_proxy=my.proxy
puppet apply "$@"
```

I'm not 100% sure where to do this, or if this is the best solution.

Surely I'm not the only one trying to use Vagrant/Puppet & Proxies?

Answer (score 1):

try setting your proxy like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export http_proxy=http://my.proxy:3128
puppet apply "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a shell provisioner in my Vagrantfile *before* the Puppet provisioner:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo 'export http_proxy=http://proxy.company.com:3128' >> /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit biased, but I would recommend using [vagrant-proxyconf](http://tmatilai.github.io/vagrant-proxyconf/) plugin. To configure all Vagrant machines, you can use *$HOME/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile* or environment variables. This way you don't need to modify all project specific Vagrantfiles.

Example:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.proxy.http  = "http://my.proxy:3128"
  config.proxy.https = "http://my.proxy:3128"
  # other configuration...
end
```